# Can't parse some xml in java

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I cannot parse this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
  <response>
     <status>OK</status>
     <time>2012-12-18 21:55</time>
  </response>
```

By code:

```
InputStream is=sock.getInputStream();
        String sa="";
        int cc;
        while((cc=is.read())!=-1){
            sa+=(char) cc;
        }
ByteArrayInputStream sr=new ByteArrayInputStream(sa.getBytes());
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db=dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc=db.parse(sr);
```

`sr` is the `String` where this is placed. How can it be possible? when I use `doc.getNodeName` i get null.

Comment: Are you sure that you got the right doc from inputstream?

Comment: I printed sa out and it was exactly as written in xml. an it be encoding problem or what?

Comment: i don't think so. did you try my answer below? you have also the possibilty to use xpath to approach this issue

Comment: but what about casual way?

Comment: there are 2 types of documents in java which one do you use here?

Comment: what do you mean with casual way?

Comment: I just try your and everything is correct. doc.getNodeName just return  document

Answer (score 0):

There is another to get your inputstream parsed. try this and you will have a full control

[parsing xml file using java for -- android based application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12855391/parsing-xml-file-using-java-for-android-based-application/12856079#12856079)

Or

```
public class Tester {

    String getString() throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
        InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("input.xml");
        String sa = "";
        int cc;
        while((cc = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
            sa += (char) cc;
        }
        ByteArrayInputStream sr = new ByteArrayInputStream(sa.getBytes());
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(sr);

        Node node=doc.getDocumentElement().getFirstChild();
        String data=node.getNodeName();
        return data;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
        Tester t = new Tester();
        System.out.println(t.getString());

    }

}
```